# Check website for update

Tags: python, url, hashcode

I have written a program in Python that checks websites for updates (it checks in anything on the website changes) and notifies the user. The idea is downloading the webpage, stripping HTML tags off it so extract the actual text and then calculating its md5 hash, so that we know when something changes. This is what my code looks right now (it's working on SOME websites). I would appreciate feedback about my style / logic / possible features that could be interesting etc. I also would like to know how to find out on which websites my code works and on which websites it doesn't work and why (for example if there are dynamic numbers that change it will mess up the MD5 hash).

```
import vlc  # needed for the music feature
import hashlib
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from pushover import init, Client  # push notifications on your phone
# set the path of the music if u use the feature
# make sure to set up pushover on your phone before u use it


def check_for_update():

    if(os.path.isfile("website.txt")):

        req = Request(url)
        try:
            response = urlopen(req)
        except HTTPError as e:
            print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
            print('Error code: ', e.code)
        except URLError as e:
            print('We failed to reach a server.')
            print('Reason: ', e.reason)
        html = urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines
                  for phrase in line.split(" "))
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        file = open("website_new.txt", "w")
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open('website_new.txt', 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
        global new_md5sum
        new_md5sum = hasher.hexdigest()
    else:

        html = urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines
                  for phrase in line.split(" "))
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        file = open("website.txt", "w")
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open('website.txt', 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
        global original_md5sum
        original_md5sum = hasher.hexdigest()
        check_for_update()


def main():

    global url
    url = input("Paste the URL you want to check for updates: ")
    global push
    while True:
        temp = input("\nDo you want to get a notification \
to your phone when the website has been changed? (y/n): ")
        if (temp != "y" and temp != "n"):
            print("Error: Please enter y or n")
        else:
            if temp == "y":
                push = True
                print("Notifications to your phone have been turned ON\n")
                break
            else:
                print("Notifications to your phone have been turned OFF\n")
                break

    global music
    while True:
        temp = input("Do you want to play a song \
when the website has been changed? (y/n): ")
        if (temp != "y" and temp != "n"):
            print("Error: Please enter y or n")
        else:
            if temp == "y":
                music = True
                print("The music feature has been turned ON\n")
                break
            else:
                print("The music feature has been turned OFF\n")
                break

    global update_timer
    while True:
        temp = input("How often do you want to check \
the website for updates? Enter it in seconds (min. 20): ")

        if (temp.isdigit()):
            temp = int(temp)
            if temp > 19:
                print("The website will be checked for \
updates every " + str(temp) + " seconds\n")
                update_timer = temp
                break
            else:
                print("Make sure to enter a value bigger than 19\n")
        else:
            print("Please enter an integer (which has to be bigger than 19)\n")

    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    try:
        os.remove(path + "/website.txt")
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.remove(path + "/website_new.txt")
    except OSError:
        pass
    original_md5sum = ""
    new_md5sum = ""
    check_for_update()
    mainloop()


def mainloop():

    while True:

        check_for_update()
        '''
        print("Original: ", original_md5sum)
        print("New: ", new_md5sum)
        '''
        if original_md5sum == new_md5sum:
            print("Website hasn't been updated yet... " +
                  datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        else:
            print("Website hat been updated! " +
                  datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

            if push is True:
                init("<token>")
                Client("<client_id>\
").send_message("Website has been updated!", title="Website update")

            if music is True:
                # example: file:///home/anon/Music/song.mp3
                p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file://<path>")
                p.play()
                time.sleep(60)
                p.stop()
            break
        time.sleep(update_timer)


main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, I really like your idea and I think with a couple of small changes it would be a really nice utility to use! To start out with, here's a couple of suggestions regarding code style:

- `import`s [are normally grouped](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

  - standard library imports
  - related third party imports
  - local application / library specific imports

  these categories should be separated by a single blank line:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  import hashlib
  import os
  import time
  from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
  from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

  from pushover import init, Client
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import vlc
  ```
- Whitespace is good, if it's used [sparingly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). Excess use of whitespace can actually reduce readability, doing only harm to your code. I personally don't put a blank line in between a function signature and its first line, but that too is mostly up to you.

Those are the only real coding style issues I can find.
Here's some other remarks about your code:

- `if`-statements don't have to be wrapped in parentheses:

  ```
  if(os.path.isfile("website.txt")):
  ```

  ... could simply become:

  ```
  if os.path.isfile("website.txt"):
  ```
- You can use a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for opening files, which is slightly more pythonic than manually calling `open()` and `close()`. The issue with dealing with files is it's essential to `close()` the file to prevent any data from being corrupted or lost. Thus, you need to wrap such a code block in a `try` / `except`-construct:

  ```
  try:
      f = open(<filename>, <mode>)
      # File operations here
  finally:
      f.close()
  ```

  ... if you forget to wrap it in such a statement, if an exception is raised while operating on a file, data may be damaged or lost. You can use context managers (the `with` statement) to automatically close the file when you release the resource:

  ```
  with open(<filename>, <mode>) as <variable>:
      # File operations follow
  # No need to call <variable>.close(), as soon as you leave the context,
  # close() is called.
  ```
- `urllib` is, frankly, a messy library. Kenneth Reiz has written [an awesome wrapper](https://github.com/requests/requests) around it, which automatically deals with underlying HTTP stuff, allowing you to focus on the actual scraping. Here's an example:

  ```
  import requests

  request = requests.get("http://httpbin.org")
  # requests automatically handles all the rest.
  assert request.status_code == 200
  webpage = request.text
  # operate on request.text (...)
  ```

  As you can see, it saves you a lot of work and time! The full documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).
- You should use `global` only when there is no other choice. Global variables make your code much harder to debug and pretty much impossible to test. For more reading up:

  - [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)
  - [Python anti-patterns - global](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/using_the_global_statement.html)
- Some of your variables are badly named. Take `buf` or `temp`. You may want to rename these to `buffer` and `get_notification`.
- I suggest your `check_for_update()` function takes arguments like `website_path` and `url` instead of relying on user input. This way, you could import this code as a module and call `<module>.check_for_update(website_path="website.txt", url=<url>)`. If you were to make this script into a module, you should probably put `main()` in a special kind of `if`-statement, called a name guard:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

  [What does if __name__ == "__main__" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- There's a real difference between `==` (equals) and `is` (is). Shortly said, `a == b` checks if the value of `a` (or, more strictly put, `a.__eq__()`) is equal to that of `b`, whereas `a is b` checks if `a` is literally the same object (in memory) as `b` (see [this StackOverflow question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)). So, when comparing to the value of `True` or `False`, you need to use `==`. But since Python automatically compares values in an `if` statement to `True`, you can leave all of that out and just do:

  ```
  if <expression>:
      # Functionally the same as `if <expression> == True:`
  if not <expression>:
      # Functionally the same as `if <expression> == False:`
  ```